# Create RTMP connection using socket programming

Tags: java, sockets, rtmp, amf, rtmps

I need to create RTMP client using java socket programming.  I read [this](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/rtmp/pdf/rtmp_specification_1.0.pdf) documents and

[1](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/rtmp/pdf/rtmp_specification_1.0.pdf) . I have performed handshaking successfully through java socket programming.

Now next step is to send 'connect' command to the server.  I am creating RTMP packet as given in document and then writing them to the output stream using DataOutputStream. As per given details 'connect' packect's body should look like as below:

```
    (Invoke) “connect”
(Transaction ID) 1.0
(Object1) { app: “sample”, flashVer: “MAC 10,2,153,2”, swfUrl: null,
              tcUrl: “rtmpt://127.0.0.1/sample “, fpad: false,
              capabilities: 9947.75 , audioCodecs: 3191, videoCodecs: 252,
              videoFunction: 1 , pageUrl: null, objectEncoding: 3.0 }
```

I could not understood  how to convert above into AMF3 encoded bytes. Should I just need to AMF encode "connect:", 1.0 ... and write to OutputStream. Also major problem is that how to encode the object (Given key value pairs). Should I encode& write to socket first keys and then AMF encoded values. Is there need to include & operators between two pairs something like http protocol's body? . I did RnD deeply but could not find the code to create this packet and write to the socket.

Please suggest.
thanks.

Comment: Why did you tag the question with c++ objective-c c ? What is the relation between your question and those tags?

Comment: Actually the question is directly related to Socket programing in any language..whether using java, c or c++.... That's why I tagged.